# why is text disappearing behind the image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Here is a link to something similar.
https://codepen.io/suez/pen/RpNXOR

```
.img {
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 2;
   border-radius: 25px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 260px;
   height: 100%;
   padding-top: 360px;
}
.img:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 900px;
   height: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-image: url(/images/art.png); 
   transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
.img:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Is there a reason why the button and text disappear behind the image when it transitions ove

Comment: Hard to tell without a working example but try adding z-index somewhere

Comment: Why do have a z-index of 2 on your image? The text is behind is likely by default on z-index of 1?

Comment: @kilves the link should provide as an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have your text & button appear on top of the image, the text & button must have a higher `z-index` than `2` because assuming that your .img class controls your image, your image is declared as `z-index: 2;`. Try adding the `z-index: 3;` declaration to both your text & button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not seem to work...I have noticed though, that once the mouse leaves the browser the text and button appear..not sure at all what the problem may be.